# expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token

Tags: c++, syntax, compiler-errors

I keep getting the message 
Graph.h: In function ‘bool has_cycle(G&)’:
Graph.h:392:5: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
I have checked all the braces the they are balanced, I can't figure out why I

the error happens at the has_cycle function. I am wondering if it is related to the template function arguments

```
#ifndef Graph_h
#define Graph_h

// --------
// includes
// --------

#include <cassert> // assert
#include <cstddef> // size_t
#include <utility> // make_pair, pair
#include <deque>  // deque
#include <unordered_map>  // unordered_map
#include <unordered_set>  // unordered set
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm> 
#include "boost/graph/exception.hpp"// not_a_dag exception

// -----
// Graph
// -----

class Graph 
{

public:

    //EdgeDescriptor Class
class EdgeDescriptor
{
    public:
        std::size_t _source; /*!< source vertex_descriptor */
        std::size_t _target; /*!< target vertex_descriptor */

    /**
     * default constructor
     */
     EdgeDescriptor()
     {}

    /**
     * constructor
     * @param s the sourse vertex_descriptor
     * @param t the target vertex_descriptor
     */
     EdgeDescriptor(std::size_t s, std::size_t t)
     {
        _source = s;
        _target = t;
     }

    /**
     * == operator for EdgeDescriptor
     * @param lhs a EdgeDescriptor
     * @param rhs a EdgeDescriptor
     * @return a bool that indicates whether the EdgeDescriptors are equal
     */
    friend bool operator == (const EdgeDescriptor& lhs, const EdgeDescriptor& rhs)
    {
        return (lhs._source == rhs._source) && (lhs._target == rhs._target);
    }

};

    // --------
    // typedefs
    // --------

    typedef std::size_t vertex_descriptor;
    typedef EdgeDescriptor edge_descriptor;

    typedef std::deque<vertex_descriptor>::iterator vertex_iterator;
    typedef std::unordered_set<edge_descriptor>::iterator edge_iterator;
    typedef std::deque<vertex_descriptor>::iterator adjacency_iterator;

    typedef std::size_t vertices_size_type;
    typedef std::size_t edges_size_type;

public:
    // --------
    // add_edge
    // --------

    /**
     * possibly add an edge_descriptor between two given vertex_descriptor to the graph
     * @param v1 a vertex_descriptor
     * @param v2 a vertex_descriptor
     * @return a pair where first of the pair is the edge_descriptor added and second of the pair indicates whether the EdgeDescriptor has been successfully added
     */
    friend std::pair<edge_descriptor, bool> add_edge (vertex_descriptor v1, vertex_descriptor v2, Graph& g) 
    {
        edge_descriptor e(v1, v2);

        //check if the edge_descriptor exists in the graph
        if(g._edges.find(e) == g._edges.end())
        {
            /* If the VertexList selector is vecS, and if either vertex descriptor u or v (which are integers) has a value greater than the current number of vertices in the graph, 
            the graph is enlarged so that the number of vertices is std::max(u,v) + 1. */
            if((v1 >= g._vertices.size()) || (v2 >= g._vertices.size()))
            {
                std::size_t new_size = std::max(v1, v2) + 1;
                g._vertices.resize(new_size);
            }

            g._targets[v1].push_back(v2); //add v1's adjacent vertex_descriptor (which is v2)

            g._edges.insert(e); //add edge_descriptor

            return std::make_pair(e, true);
        }
        else
        {
            return std::make_pair(e, false);
        }
    }

    // ----------
    // add_vertex
    // ----------

    /**
     * add a vertex_descriptor to the graph
     * @param g the graph where vertex_descriptor is added
     * @return the vertex_descriptor added
     */
    friend vertex_descriptor add_vertex (Graph& g) 
    {
        g._vertices.push_back((g._vertices.size()) + 1);
        return g._vertices.back();
    }

    // -----------------
    // adjacent_vertices
    // -----------------

    /**
     * adjacent_vertices function
     * @param v a vertex_descriptor
     * @param g the graph where the vertex_descriptor is
     * @return a pair of adjacency_iterators, where the first iterator can travel to the second one the eventually visit all the adjacent vertices of the vertex_descriptor
     */
    friend std::pair<adjacency_iterator, adjacency_iterator> adjacent_vertices (vertex_descriptor v,  Graph& g) 
    {
        return std::make_pair(((g._targets.find(v))->second).begin(), ((g._targets.find(v))->second).end());
    }

    // ----
    // edge
    // ----

    /**
     * edge function
     * @param v1 a vertex_descriptor
     * @param v2 a vertex_descriptor
     * @param g the graph where the vertex_descriptor is
     * @return a pair, where first is the edge_descriptor between the vertices, second is a bool indicates whether the edge_descriptor exists in the graph
     */
    friend std::pair<edge_descriptor, bool> edge (vertex_descriptor v1, vertex_descriptor v2, const Graph& g) 
    {
        edge_descriptor e(v1, v2);
        if(g._edges.find(e) == g._edges.end())
        {
            return std::make_pair(e, true);
        }
        else
        {
            return std::make_pair(e, false);
        }
    }

    // -----
    // edges
    // -----

    /**
     * edges function
     * @param g a Graph
     * @return a pair of edge_iterator in which the first can travel to the second one the eventually visits all the edges in the given graph
     */
    friend std::pair<edge_iterator, edge_iterator> edges (Graph& g) 
    {
        return std::make_pair(g._edges.begin(), g._edges.end());
    }

    // ---------
    // num_edge
    // ---------

    /**
     * num_edge function
     * @param g a Graph
     * @return the number of edges in the given graph
     */
    friend edges_size_type num_edge (const Graph& g) 
    {
        return g._edges.size();
    }

    // ------------
    // num_vertices
    // ------------

    /**
     * num_vertices function
     * @param g a Graph
     * @return the number of vertices in the given graph
     */
    friend vertices_size_type num_vertices (const Graph& g) 
    {
        return g._vertices.size();
    }

    // ------
    // source
    // ------

    /**
     * source function
     * @param r an edge_descriptor
     * @param g a Graph
     * @return the source vertex_descriptor of a given edge_descriptor in the given graph
     */
    friend vertex_descriptor source (edge_descriptor e, const Graph& g) 
    {
        return (g._edges.find(e))->_source;
    }

    // ------
    // target
    // ------

    /**
     * target function
     * @param e an edge_descriptor
     * @param g a Graph
     * @return the target vertex_descriptor of a given edge_descriptor in the given graph
     */
    friend vertex_descriptor target (edge_descriptor e, const Graph& g) 
    {
        return (g._edges.find(e))->_target;
    }

    // ------
    // vertex
    // ------

    /**
     * vertex function
     * @param nth integral value represents the n term index of the vertex
     * @param g a Graph
     * @return the nth vertex_descriptor of the graph
     */
    friend vertex_descriptor vertex (vertices_size_type nth, const Graph& g) 
    {
        return g._vertices[nth];
    }

    // --------
    // vertices
    // --------

    /**
     * vertices function
     * @param g a Graph
     * @return a pair of vertex_iterator in which the first can travel to the second one the eventually visits all the vertices in the given graph
     */
    friend std::pair<vertex_iterator, vertex_iterator> vertices (Graph& g) 
    {
        return std::make_pair(g._vertices.begin(), g._vertices.end());
    }

private:
    // ----
    // data
    // ----

    std::deque<vertex_descriptor> _vertices; /*!< container of the vertex_descriptors */

    std::unordered_set<edge_descriptor> _edges; /*!< container of the edge_descriptors */

    std::unordered_map<vertex_descriptor, std::deque<vertex_descriptor> > _targets; /*!< keep track of the adjacent vertices (vertex_descriptor that vertex_descriptors points to). Key is the vertex_descriptor that owns the adjacent vertex_descriptors*/


    // -----
    // valid
    // -----

    /**
     * valid function
     */
    bool valid () const 
    {
        return _vertices.size() == 0 && _edges.size() == 0 && _targets.size() == 0;
    }

public:
    // ------------
    // constructors
    // ------------

    /**
     *  default constructor
     */
    Graph () : _vertices(), _edges(), _targets()
    {
        assert(valid());
    }

    // Default copy, destructor, and copy assignment
    // Graph  (const Graph<T>&);
    // ~Graph ();
    // Graph& operator = (const Graph&);
};

//helper function for has_cycle
template <typename G>
bool has_grey_neighbour (const G& g, typename G::vertex_descriptor v, std::vector<int>& colors)
{
return std::any_of(adjacent_vertices(v, g).first, adjacent_vertices(v, g).second, [&colors](typename G::vertex_descriptor v)
    {
        return colors[v] == 1;
    });
}

//helper function for DFS (return -1 if no)
template <typename G>
int get_white_vertex (const G& g, std::vector<int>& colors)
{
int result = -1;
int count = 0;
while(count < colors.size() && result == -1)
{
    if(colors[count] == 0)
    {
        result = count;
    }
    ++count;
}
return result;
}

//helper function for DFS (return -1 if no white neighbour)
template <typename G>
int get_white_neighbour (const G& g, typename G::vertex_descriptor v, std::vector<int>& colors)
{
typename G::adjacency_iterator match;
match = std::find_if(adjacent_vertices(v, g).first, adjacent_vertices(v, g).second, [&colors](typename G::vertex_descriptor v)
    {
        return colors[v] == 0;
    });
if(match == adjacent_vertices(v, g).second)
{
    return -1;
}
else
{
    return (int)(*match);
}
}

// ---------
// has_cycle
// ---------

/**
* depth-first traversal
* three colors
* @param g a Graph
* @return bool indicates whether the graph is cyclic
*/
template <typename G>
bool has_cycle (const G& g) 
{
if(num_vertices(g) == 0)
{
    return false;
}

std::vector<int> colors(num_vertices(g), 0); //keep track of the different colors of vertices (0 while, 1 grey, 2 black)
std::deque<typename G::vertex_descriptor> s; //use as a stack
typename G::vertex_descriptor current_vertex;
int current_vertex_index;
int next_vertex_index;
bool stack_empty;

whlie(get_white_vertex(g, colors) != -1)
{
    current_vertex_index = get_white_vertex(g, colors);
    current_vertex = vertex(current_vertex_index, g);
    colors[current_vertex_index] = 1;
    do
    {
        if(has_grey_neighbour(g, current_vertex, colors))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if((next_vertex_index = get_white_neighbour(g, current_vertex, colors)) != -1)
        {
            colors[next_vertex_index] = 1;
            s.push_back(current_vertex);
            current_vertex = vertex(next_vertex_index, g);
            current_vertex_index = (int)current_vertex;
        }
        else
        {
            colors[current_vertex_index] = 2;
            if(!(stack_empty = s.empty()))
            {
                current_vertex = s.back();
                current_vertex_index = (int)current_vertex;
                s.pop_back();
            }
        }
    }while(!stack_empty);
}
return false;
}

// ----------------
// topological_sort
// ----------------

/**
* depth-first traversal
* two colors
* performs a topological sort on a graph and stream the outoput to an output iterator
* @param g a Graph
* @param x an output iteration
* @throws Boost's not_a_dag exception if has_cycle()
*/
template <typename G, typename OI>
void topological_sort (const G& g, OI x) 
{
if(has_cycle(g))
{
    throw boost::not_a_dag();
}
else
{
    std::vector<int> colors(num_vertices(g), 0); //keep track of the different colors of vertices (0 while, 1 grey, 2 black)
    std::deque<typename G::vertex_descriptor> s; //use as a stack
    int current_vertex_index;
    int next_vertex_index;
    bool stack_empty;
    typename G::vertex_descriptor current_vertex;

    std::deque<typename G::vertex_descriptor> result;

whlie((current_vertex_index = get_white_vertex(g, colors)) != -1)
{
    current_vertex = vertex(current_vertex_index, g);
    colors[current_vertex_index] = 1;
    do
    {
        if((next_vertex_index = get_white_neighbour(g, current_vertex, colors)) != -1)
        {
            colors[next_vertex_index] = 1;
            s.push_back(current_vertex);
            current_vertex = vertex(next_vertex_index, g);
            current_vertex_index = (int)current_vertex;
        }
        else
        {
            colors[current_vertex_index] = 2;
            if(!(stack_empty = s.empty()))
            {
                current_vertex = s.back();
                current_vertex_index = (int)current_vertex;
                s.pop_back();
            }
        }
    }while(!stack_empty);
}   

    while(!result.empty())
    {
        *x = result.back();
        result.pop_back();
        ++x;
    }
}
}

#endif // Graph_h
```

Comment: You might need to post the .cpp file that's being compiled.

Comment: And you posted nearly 500 lines of code for a syntax error - this type of error you will encounter throughout your working life if you stay in programming. The compiler is telling you where the problem is.

Answer (score 5):

`While` is misspelled on this line:

```
 whlie((current_vertex_index = get_white_vertex(g, colors)) != -1)
```

Comment: If this answered your question you should accept it as the answer.